# What value should be the value of the optional `Timeout` value when using continuous move ONVIF

Tags: c#, wsdl, onvif

I've added a service reference to the ONVIF PTZ wsdl (`https://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl`) to my c# windows form camera app.

I've created a `PTZClient` and I am able to send ptz commands.

I've looked at the PTZ wsdl's documentation and it is stated that the `Timeout` value is optional for the `ContinuousMove` operation.

When I try to put nothing in this input, in my code, I get an error saying that there is no definition of the `ContinuousMove` without a `Timeout`.

So my question is:
**What value should I put there?**

I've looked through wireshark at packets sent by the `ONVIF Device Manager` demo app but can't figure where this value is...

[image: wireshark continuous move]

My c# winform app is basically sending a `ContinuousMove` command when a button is pressed and a `Stop` command when a button is released.

I don't know if this is related, but when I use `"PT5S"` as value for my timeout, It seems to work, but when I hold my buttons, for more than 5 sec, the movement of my camera stops. And when I spam click my button, my camera just freezes and reboots...

I've tried doing the same two things in the ONVIF Device manager, but my camera won't freeze or stop after 5 sec of movement.

Comment: You're right, neither the documentation nor the WSDSL specifies the required unit of the timeout value; milliseconds, seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I could put `null` as variable.